# Is there a way to guess the keyword traffic for a specific URL using just search engines and page source?

Tags: search-engines, keywords, traffic, competitors

For example, is it possible to guess which keyword searches are driving people to `https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-14-04` using just search engines and their page source, to help me figure out what keywords I should use?

Comment: From the page title it looks like a long tail search. What search terms have you tried to see if it comes up?

Comment: (Sigh.) SEO is **not** about keywords. Any search term match is incidental to the semantic analysis that takes place. Otherwise, SEOs will have you believe that search engines are matching terms when it is not. The reason for the keyword chase is to keep you hooked and dependent upon their site or service to compete in the keyword chase. It is all a game. I do not need to remind you that most SEOs are not technical people and parrot the same ole' cr@p from site to site. It is how they try and carve out a space in the market. What is sad is most of these sites fail miserably. Please stop.

Comment: @closetnoc Interesting, I agree with this when it comes to large websites and teams with large resources, however My experience differs, for small websites. I have had great results with on page keyword optimisation - again I have to qualify - the term great . I mean hundreds of views per month for otherwise uncompetitive and low ranking and/or long tail keywords. The reason why I like this keyword "technical" approach is because you dont need any reputation or confirmation from other 3rd parties about your content. Although the game runs out on my strategy pretty quickly!

Comment: @the_velour_fog The principle problem with the keyword chase is that sites over optimize for terms and lose out on search potential labeled as long-tail. Keyword match and keyword density is a myth. However, paying attention to appropriate language for a given niche is correct. It is all about context and linguistics. A properly developed site will perform for search terms that do not exist on the site or page. Otherwise, focusing too heavily on term matches misleads/disappoints the user who ultimately finds the site through artificial means.

Comment: @closetnoc Interesting, I definitely agree with that - basically long-tail is all I typically look as they are typically whats achievable for me. I usually don't bother going for "trophy" keywords  - too hard. Again, to qualify, I just know about how to get small websites "on the radar" (and that took a long time) but Im interested to learn how bigger players get their results.

Comment: Many SEOs talk about semantics. I am one of them - sorta. However, very little of the HTML mark-up makes much of a difference. What makes a difference is semantics as it applies to linguistics. This is because this is primarily what search engines use over any mark-up short of the title tag, link text, URL/URI, description meta-tag, h1 tag, and then the content itself. Semantics applied to linguistics has been applied for a very long time in search. The reason is context and the ability to know which meaning of a term applies. Taking advantage of semantics fully is paramount.

Comment: @closetnoc yes I agree with this and your comments below about context. I havent had any direct experience with problems of being too optimised, but I know what you mean and Matt Cutts himself suggests mixing content up a bit to prevent over-optimisation. For me when things get to that point I generally go off and work on something else because it gets so fuzzy how to improve the page anymore.

Comment: @the_velour_fog It is amazing what a sit on the back porch and a smoke can do... just do not smoke the wrong stuff or you really will be fuzzy! Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to guess the keyword traffic for a specific URL using just search engines and page source?

No, a search engine needs *you* to tell it the search terms and it gives you content as results - but I believe you want to be told what keywords/search terms (that you have been unable to guess yourself) generate traffic to this URL.
You need a service which has essentially reverse engineered the search process.
SEM Rush provides this service, here is the [result for the URL you are interested in](https://www.semrush.com/info/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.digitalocean.com%2Fcommunity%2Ftutorials%2Fhow-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-14-04?db=us)

Table: TOP ORGANIC RESULTS

```
Keyword                     Pos. Volume  CPC (USD)
install postgresql ubuntu   2    480     0.00
ubuntu install postgres     2    320     0.00
ubuntu postgresql           2    320     0.00
install postgres ubuntu     2    260     0.00
postgresql ubuntu           2    210     0.00
```

So the top result is `install postgresql ubuntu`, this doesn't tell you that 480 searchers typed `install postgresql ubuntu` into google and then clicked into your URL, instead it tells you

- for the **US version** of Google
- 480 searchers queried `install postgresql ubuntu` into US google
- your URL was positioned 2 in the first page of results
- you can then *infer* a guess at the clickthroughs - e.g. say position 2 google results have an average clickthrough of 10%
- So you can estimate that if you had a URL (landing page) that ranked in the same position for the same keyword you might get 48 visitors per month from google.

Assuming I understood your question correctly this will give you what you want, a list of high traffic keywords this page is ranking for.

Comment: SEMRush and others use one or two term searches to see what sites appear within the SERPs. The problem with this is there is no context. One or two term searches are rare and contain no semantic clues and default to low probability results. For example, I could search for my friend by his whole name which has an animal name for a last name. Because of over optimization and lack of context, my friend will not appear within the SERPs even when quoted. However, if I add attorney before the name, context takes over and my friend can be found as a lawyer when the term attorney is not used.

Answer (score 1):

**If you own website:**

Just go to Google webmaster >> Search Analytics >> Mark on position, Clicks and impression, and you will get all the data in your hand.

**To test on other website:**

If you want to test on other website, then first of, there is no any software, that track all the keywords/quires on particular webpage, yes **tools like semrush, wordtracker and longtail pro help in someway, but that can't track all the keywords that drive traffic to specific webpage**, they are PPC spy tool, and using third party API like Google adwords.

Google never gives that type of information though API, because they don't want, war of keyword on internet.

Comment: You bring up a good point about these tools being PPC oriented. They are skewed toward search term value in relation to dollars and not as much performance in the SERPs per se'.